# Android Package Sniffing

Tags: android, api, networking, wifi

How can an android application capture raw wifi packets?  I am trying to create a packet sniffer.  However, I have not found a library capable of listening to a WLAN channel.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The following is a list of libraries that appeared promising but did not work out:

- **[java.net](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html)**

  - Java Standard Library
  - Uses sockets
- **[android.net.wifi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html)**

  - Android Standard Library
  - No listening capabilities
- **[jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/)**

  - Purpose-built package capture library
  - Requires the JNI (not available on android)

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have any api for listening network packets. You should be able to use tcpdump(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump).